# Optimal reduction using token-passing nets

Tags: computer-science, lambda-calculus

I am looking for implementation of optimal reduction for λ-calculus based on interaction nets ([McCarthy's amb](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571066105803639) allowed) in the spirit of ["Token-Passing Nets: Call-by-Need for Free" by François-Régis Sinot](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571066106000934). Implementations of optimal reduction that I am aware of either assume a specific strategy for the interaction net reduction, or involve non-pure graph reductions rather than just interaction rules.

The reason why I am interested in such implementation is that I already have a [compiler](https://codedot.github.io/lambda/) for interaction nets which is based on interaction calculus, but is agnostic to any notion of interface, thus unable to follow any strategy while reducing a configuration simply represented as a queue of active pairs.

Comment: Might this be more appropriate at http://cs.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: It might, indeed. I just asked this question there as well http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32602/call-by-need-optimal-reduction-using-interaction-nets

Comment: I managed to derive a token-passing net implementation of optimal reduction codedot.dreamwidth.org/174955.html by introducing a waiting construct. However it results in too much overhead and significantly worse overall performance than call-by-need implementation by Sinot.